# Deleting from files

Tags: python-3.x

(I have only been learning Python3 for about 2 weeks now. So if you could keep the answer as ELI5 as possible that would be great)

[In this image, I have first read the file and then second zeroed the file and recreated it while removing all the lines containing 'Ford'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/014YX.png)

[This image shows the contents of the file that I wish to be printed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HUiB.png)

The problem I have is that the result is being printed as 'none'.

How would I make it so this program prints out what is inside the file?

Thanks!

code below

```
def delete_ford(path, term):
buffer = []
with open(path, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        buffer.append(line.strip())
with open(path, "w") as file:
    for line in buffer:
        if line != term:
            file.write(line + "\n")
with open(path, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        buffer.append(line.strip())
        print(buffer)
print(delete_ford("cars.txt", "Ford"))
```

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: Should be up now

Comment: Your function does not return anything, so it implicitly returns None, which you print out.

Comment: so just adding 'return(buffer)' should fix?

Comment: Just call the function delete_ford("cars.txt", "Ford"). The function returns nothing so you have got nothing to print.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Zwinck and @Albert Alberto pointed out, your function has nothing to return as the output is written to the file.

If you want it simply to print out the contents of the file, you can do this when you're writing to it like this:

```py
with open(path, "w") as file:
    for line in buffer:
        if line != term:
            file.write(line + "\n") # This is what is being written to the file
            print(line) # So this will effectively output the contents of the file
```

Hope this does what you want it to